# WindowServer Crashes MacBook Pro Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, crash

I have been getting fairly frequent WindowServer crashes on MacOS Catalina.

When this happens I can move the mouse, but I can't click on anything or type. I can also hear sound for a couple minutes and then ultimately the computer reboots.

I have a MacBook Pro 2019 15".

How can I debug this type of issue?

Comment: Start with booting into Safe mode and then see if any third party stuff is interfering

Comment: Also you can look in the logs via the console.app in /Applications/Utilities

Comment: @SteveChambers What should I be looking for in the Spin Reports?

Comment: unusual events. Honestly reading the logs is not fun, easy and seemingly requires a degree in UNIX. The times I have found useful info in the logs are rare. But if you find something that looks like it MIGHT be a problem, add it to your question as there are folks here that *DO* understand and speak macOS Log